# Does the lack of an image automatically mean an identify-this-game question should be closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

In the question [What game do these dice belong to](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/54225/what-game-do-these-dice-belong-to) the poster gave a complete description of the game components he had (and which as it turns out are very uncommon if not unique to the target game) and yet the question was closed as being either unclear or in need of details.

Is a picture required for such questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this case it's sufficiently clear, so I voted to reopen. The tag wiki even says

> *"A game on a blue polka dot board with yellow dinosaur pieces from the early 90s"* is great.

so while a picture may be very helpful (and I edited the tag excerpt and wiki to reflect that) it isn't required.